# Automatically build PDF from markdown using hugo on github/netlify

Tags: pdf, github, markdown, hugo, netlify

I'm using `hugo` (`academic` theme) to build a website from sources on `github`, built and hosted on `netlify`.

In this site I have one particular page which is rendered from a `markdown` file (`.md`) and which I would also like to have available as `.pdf`.
Currently I have to manually generate and push the `.pdf` every time an edit is made to the `.md` source, but I'd like this to be automated.

An approach I tried is to embed a JavaScript `window.print()` button in the page, so that users can print the page to file, but this is somewhat inelegant.

I'm not sure if this can be done via `hugo`, via a `github` or `netlify` hook, or something else.

Any pointers to the right approach are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit more research,
it seems that the best way to accomplish this would be using a continuous integration tool such as Travis.
There are several possible approaches to this, including:

1. https://harshjv.com/blog/setup-latex-pdf-build-using-travis-ci/
2. https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf
3. https://gist.github.com/willprice/e07efd73fb7f13f917ea
4. https://vaibhavsagar.com/blog/2015/02/26/automate-resume/
5. https://github.com/livioso/pandoc-travis-setup

All the approaches are quite similar and basically do the following:

1. Create a GitHub authorisation token
2. Instruct Travis-CI to build the PDF on new commits
3. Upload the PDF to your chosen branch and location